# Does the output manipulator std::ends add a Null-character to the output buffer?

Tags: c++, stream, manipulators

Again reading C++ primer 5ed I have a simple question:

It is said that the manipulator `std::ends` inserts a Null-character `\0` to the output buffer then flushes it.

So I tried to understand it through an example:

```
#include <iostream>


int main() {

    char sz[]{ 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '!' }; // no null-terminator character ('\0')
    std::cout << sz; // Hello!
    std::cout << sz << std::flush;
    std::cout << sz << std::ends;

}
```

Above in the first output line I get some unreadable characters appended to the array of characters; Ok because I didn't add a null-character `\0` to `sz`.

- In the second line it is OK the output looks like the first but forces flushing the buffer.
- What matters me the third line using `std::ends`; it is said that this manipulator inserts a Null-Character into the output buffer but the output is the same as the lines above it; Which prints unreadable trailing characters which I guess that `std::ends` didn't insert `\0` in the output buffer?!

Here is the output:

```
Hello!╠╠╠╠╠╠ظش↕♠L·6
Hello!╠╠╠╠╠╠ظش↕♠L·6Hello!╠╠╠╠╠╠ظش↕♠L·6
```

Thank you.

Comment: After `std::cout << sz; // Hello!` your program is in undefined behaviour land.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: How come?

Comment: Because you are accessing memory that is not part of the array.

Comment: 3rd line, it's already output the unterminated buffer before outputing the `\0`.  So you get case (2) plus a trailing `\0`

Comment: In other words the 3rd line outputs all of `sz` and trailing memory first, and then theoretically outputs a `\0` after all that.

Comment: @TheUndeadFish: Got it. But what is the point in adding `\0` then?

Comment: @Maestro [per cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/ends): "*This manipulator [`std::ends`] is typically used with `std::ostrstream`, when the associated output buffer needs to be null-terminated to be processed as a C string.*"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::ends` is an archaic manipulator intended to be used for the now-deprecated array I/O streams like `std::strstream`, `std::istrstream`, and `std::ostrstream`. You will rarely if ever have to use it in practice.

The problem in your code is that `std::cout << sz << std::ends` first executes `std::cout << sz` which will print the character array. The extractor overload over character arrays is designed to continue printing each character until it finds a null terminator. `sz` does not end with one so the extractor is just going to keep iterating past the end of the array until it encounters a random null character in surrounding memory. What results from this is called **undefined behavior**. The compiler no longer has to conform to the logic of your code, and therefore the output can be meaningless garbage or it could print it in a way that appears like the code is working. Undefined behavior means undefined.

Adding `<< std::ends` will not null-terminate the character array, it's a separate operation that executes *after* the first expression has been executed.

If you'd like to print the character array as-is I would recommend using `write`:

```
std::cout.write(sz, sizeof(sz));
```

Comment: Really interesting and clear explaining! Thank you always for your precious help.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Memory over-write is also case of `UB` ? just want to confirm.

Comment: @Abhishek Yes, writing over memory that was not allocated for you will cause undefined behavior.